# Newton's square root method in Scheme or Common Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp

I am not able to figure out the error in this program. This is the Scheme version. I tried Common Lisp version as well. In both cases, the program keeps running without any result. Please help.

```
(define (sqrt1 x)

  (define (square x)
      (* x x))

  (define (isGoodEnough g x)
      (< (abs (- (square g) (square x))) 0.01))

  (define (average x y)
      (/ (+ x y) 2))

  (define (improvedGuess g x)
      (average g (/ x g)))

  (define (sqrt-iter g x)
      (if (isGoodEnough g x)
          g
          (sqrt-iter (improvedGuess g x) x)))

  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isGoodEnough` has a bug. You're squaring both the current guess `g` and also the number `x`. But since `g` is supposed to be the square root of `x`, they'll never be close if you square both of them. You should only square the guess.

```
(define (isGoodEnough g x)
  (< (abs (- (square g) x)) 0.01))
```

Comment: Damn! :( Thanks Barmer for this quick response.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to find the problem yourself. I'll show you how to do it. I'll be using LispWorks, but it works in similar ways with most Lisp implementations.

This is your code in Common Lisp:

```
(defun square (x)
  (* x x))

(defun isGoodEnough (g x)
  (< (abs (- (square g)
             (square x)))
     0.01))

(defun average (x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(defun improvedGuess (g x)
  (average g (/ x g)))

(defun sqrt-iter (g x)
  (if (isGoodEnough g x)
      g
    (sqrt-iter (improvedGuess g x) x)))

(defun sqrt1 (x)
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

I've evaluated the code with LispWorks now.

Let's try to compute the square root of `2.0`:

```
CL-USER 8 > (sqrt1 2.0)
```

LispWorks gives a stack overflow, but we could have interrupted it manually if it were in an endless loop:

```
Stack overflow (stack size 53998).
  1 (continue) Extend stack by 50%.
  2 (abort) Return to level 0.
  3 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.
```

`CL-USER 9 : 1 >` is the prompt. In the package `CL-USER`, nine forms evaluated in the listener and in break loop level one.

`:bq` is the command for a quick backtrace overview:

```
CL-USER 9 : 1 > :bq

ERROR <- AVERAGE <- IMPROVEDGUESS <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER
<- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER
<- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER
...
<- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER
<- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- SQRT-ITER <- EVAL
<- CAPI::CAPI-TOP-LEVEL-FUNCTION <- CAPI::INTERACTIVE-PANE-TOP-LOOP
<- MP::PROCESS-SG-FUNCTION
```

`:n` is the command to go to the next stack frame.

```
CL-USER 10 : 1 > :n
Interpreted call to AVERAGE

CL-USER 11 : 1 > :n
Interpreted call to IMPROVEDGUESS

CL-USER 12 : 1 > :n
Interpreted call to SQRT-ITER
```

`:v` is the command to look at the variable values for that stack frame. We look at this and the next frame to see how the function got called.

```
CL-USER 13 : 1 > :v
Interpreted call to SQRT-ITER:
  G : 1.4142135                    ; current guess
  X : 2.0

CL-USER 14 : 1 > :n
Interpreted call to SQRT-ITER

CL-USER 15 : 1 > :v
Interpreted call to SQRT-ITER:
  G : 1.4142135                    ; prior guess
  X : 2.0
```

So the current guess and the prior guess are equal.

Look at your code:

```
(defun sqrt-iter (g x)
  (if (isGoodEnough g x)
      g
    (sqrt-iter (improvedGuess g x) x)))
```

This recursive call happens only if the guess is not good enough.
Check it using the current values:

```
CL-USER 16 : 1 > (isgoodenough 1.4142135 2.0)
NIL
```

But it should be T, since the guess is actually good enough.
There is a bug!! Let's look at the code:

```
(defun isGoodEnough (g x)
  (< (abs (- (square g)
             (square x)))
     0.01))
```

Hmm, you are squaring both. `1.4142135` and `2.0`. That's wrong. Let's change it to not square the value for `x:

```
CL-USER 17 : 1 > (defun isGoodEnough (g x)
                   (< (abs (- (square g)
                              x))
                      0.01))
ISGOODENOUGH
```

Verify:

```
CL-USER 18 : 1 > (isgoodenough 1.4142135 2.0)
T
```

Now LispWorks is cool and let's you restart the current call `(sqrt-iter 1.4142135 2.0)` using the `:res` command:

```
CL-USER 19 : 1 > :res
1.4142135

CL-USER 20 >
```

We got a good enough result and LispWorks is then back at the top-level: `1.4142135`.